# Select-Object on List without converting list to object in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to deep filter a PowerShell Object and convert it to JSON using Select-Object. Select-Object works fine on properties of objects, but it deforms lists.

A list containing 1 element is converted into an object. A list containing more than 1 element is converted into an object with properties: `value` and `count`.

I have tried using `ExpandProperty` and `ForEach-Property` but had no success.

Example:
In the example below, `StorageQoSPolicies` is an array.

Code:

```
$Cloud = Get-SCCloud -ID 'bbf6a193-4439-4053-9772-7228e3be3db9'; 
function Expand-SCCloud() {
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipeline = $true)
    ] $rawObj
  ) 
  $CloudCapacity_Filter_001 = @{Name = 'CloudCapacity'; Expression = { $_.CloudCapacity | Select-Object CPUCount, MemoryMB, VMCount } };
  $StorageQoSPolicies_Filter_002 = @{Name = 'StorageQoSPolicies'; Expression = { $_.StorageQoSPolicies | Select-Object IOPSMaximum, IOPSMinimum, BandwidthLimit, ID, PolicyID, Name } };
  $rawObj_json = $rawObj | Select-Object Name, $CloudCapacity_Filter_001, $StorageQoSPolicies_Filter_002 | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 3;
  return $rawObj_json; 
};
$Cloud | Expand-SCCloud;
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Name": "cloud-qos",
  "CloudCapacity": {
    "CPUCount": 10,
    "MemoryMB": 10240,
    "VMCount": 10
  },
  "StorageQoSPolicies": {
    "value": [
      {
        "IOPSMaximum": 512,
        "IOPSMinimum": 64,
        "BandwidthLimit": 268435456,
        "ID": "e2a05b3a-a03e-4f73-b1f4-8b34c25ae6ff",
        "PolicyId": "dbc21acc-f039-4bc2-8730-8da2a5c8827f",
        "Name": "arc-qos-2"
      },
      {
        "IOPSMaximum": 256,
        "IOPSMinimum": 32,
        "BandwidthLimit": 268435456,
        "ID": "bd2e714f-57ae-45ae-bfb5-d1afb6c6514e",
        "PolicyId": "0c31ac02-1a19-4ebb-b360-35eb2f0aa2e7",
        "Name": "arc-qos-1"
      }
    ],
    "Count": 2
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "Name": "cloud-qos",
  "CloudCapacity": {
    "CPUCount": 10,
    "MemoryMB": 10240,
    "VMCount": 10
  },
  "StorageQoSPolicies": [
    {
      "IOPSMaximum": 512,
      "IOPSMinimum": 64,
      "BandwidthLimit": 268435456,
      "ID": "e2a05b3a-a03e-4f73-b1f4-8b34c25ae6ff",
      "PolicyId": "dbc21acc-f039-4bc2-8730-8da2a5c8827f",
      "Name": "arc-qos-2"
    },
    {
      "IOPSMaximum": 256,
      "IOPSMinimum": 32,
      "BandwidthLimit": 268435456,
      "ID": "bd2e714f-57ae-45ae-bfb5-d1afb6c6514e",
      "PolicyId": "0c31ac02-1a19-4ebb-b360-35eb2f0aa2e7",
      "Name": "arc-qos-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's because of the way you have line 11 written.  You're essentially telling it to select two whole objects, so they're being grouped.  You should really build a custom object instead of doing all this select stuff with enumeration.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Seems like you're overcomplicating things with `Select-Object` when you could be casting a `PSCustomObject` with the properties you need.

Comment: @Colyn1337, I realized the issue. I have been trying to keep the script short and readable, so have been avoiding building custom objects. Santiago's script is working, but is there any shorter way?

Comment: @nascarsayan I applaud your focus on writing quality, though let me guide you in a different direction.  Don't focus on length, instead, focus on speed of readability.  It's better to have 5 lines that take 1 minute to read than 1 line that takes 5 minutes to read.  Length is ok so long as the readability flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell if this is what you need without having access to the original object but try it and let me know.

```
$Cloud = Get-SCCloud -ID 'bbf6a193-4439-4053-9772-7228e3be3db9'; 

function Expand-SCCloud {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
    $rawObj
)

    process
    {
        $storagePolicies = $rawObj.StorageQoSPolicies | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                IOPSMaximum = $_.IOPSMaximum
                IOPSMinimum = $_.IOPSMinimum
                BandwidthLimit = $_.BandwidthLimit
                ID = $_.ID
                PolicyID = $_.Name
            }
        }

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $rawObj.Name
            CloudCapacity = $rawObj.CloudCapacity | Select-Object CPUCount, MemoryMB, VMCount
            StorageQoSPolicies = $storagePolicies
        } | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 3
    }
}

$Cloud | Expand-SCCloud;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The output matches the desired output. I have been trying to keep the script short, that's why didn't try building PSCustomObject.

Comment: @nascarsayan great. glad it worked. note that, if `$rawObj.CloudCapacity` also contains more than 1 item, I believe you will get the same issue you had with `StorageQoSPolicies`

Comment: Yup. That will happen. That's why with increasing lists the script will grow quite fast. If you can think of a shorter script, please let me know.

Comment: @nascarsayan what you're asking is unrelated to the question. you can use `psobject.properties.name` to loop through the object properties and automatically cast `pscustomobject` independently of the number of properties...